# How to set the maxitem of autocomplete dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is my code for  multi autocomplete.
How to set the max item dynamically on the basis of another text field?

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    var url2 = "<?php echo SITE_URL ?>" +'transactions/distributers_name';
    $("#dist_name").autocomplete({
        json_url: url2,
        cache: false,
        json_cache: false,
        filter_hide: false,
        firstselected: true,
        delay: 10,
        tree: false,
        maxitems: 5,
        extraparam: true,
        assignee: true,
        match_type: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way :

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    var url2 = "<?php echo SITE_URL ?>" +'transactions/distributers_name';
    $("#dist_name").autocomplete({
        json_url: url2,
        cache: false,
        json_cache: false,
        filter_hide: false,
        firstselected: true,
        delay: 10,
        tree: false,
        maxitems: "<?php echo $var_from_db; ?>",
        extraparam: true,
        assignee: true,
        match_type: true
    });
});
</script>
```

if you want it change on other field try this:

```
<script>
     $(function () {
        var dynamic="";
        $("#otherfield").keyup(function(){
           dynamic=$(this).val();
        });
        var url2 = "<?php echo SITE_URL ?>" +'transactions/distributers_name';
        $("#dist_name").autocomplete({
            json_url: url2,
            cache: false,
            json_cache: false,
            filter_hide: false,
            firstselected: true,
            delay: 10,
            tree: false,
            maxitems: dynamic,
            extraparam: true,
            assignee: true,
            match_type: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: this will work
but i want to do it on the basis of another text field.

Comment: you mean , you have input field , when input field keyup , this change automatically?

Comment: do u want me to assign var dynamic to maxitems?

Comment: no error but it only take 1 at a time as i  set that dynamic var to 1 at start . no change after dat.

Comment: Try `blur` change `keyup` to it!

Comment: do you have teamviewer software ?

Comment: hmmm :) , if you can debug your problem i think you can fix it, only check your browser console to see whats happen.if it doesn't work , you must see the error in console.

Comment: i assure u there is no error in the console and i have alert dat var dynamic it is also showing value but the autocomplete does not change accordingly.

Comment: change your method.use function for `$("#dist_name").autocomplete({
            json_url: url2,
            cache: false,
            json_cache: false,
            filter_hide: false,
            firstselected: true,
            delay: 10,
            tree: false,
            maxitems: dynamic,
            extraparam: true,
            assignee: true,
            match_type: true
        });` and get 2 parameter for this function , one url , and dynamic, then try again